# Why is Rails' ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore Not Appropriate for Large Applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

In the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memorystore), it is stated that the memory store isn't good for large deployments, but it doesn't say why:

"This cache store is not appropriate for large application deployments"

Answer (score 0):

In a production application deployment you will have many processes running your Rails app on many servers. Your `MemoryStore` cache will be unique to each process. This doesn't allow them to share cache, and compounds the work of warming and invalidation. From the doc:

> If you’re running multiple Ruby on Rails server processes (which is the case if you’re using mongrel_cluster or Phusion Passenger), then your Rails server process instances won’t be able to share cache data with each other. This cache store is not appropriate for large application deployments, but can work well for small, low traffic sites with only a couple of server processes or for development and test environments.